# Texto em inglês em alguns lugares

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Porque algumas partes do Site esta escrito em inglês como em [Reputação e moderação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> Central de ajuda > Reputação e moderação
>
> What is a bounty? How can I start one?

Se você fez uma boa pergunta, editou-a com atualizações de status e progresso e ainda não está recebendo respostas, é possível atrair a atenção para ela colocando uma gratificação.

Comment: Cria uma pergunta nova para cada um dos problemas de tradução que encontras-te para tentarmos resolver. Alguns se calhar têm perguntas abertas mas é bom receberem nova atênção.

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2705/3635

Answer (score 4):

[Traduzido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)!