# Medalhas com descrição em Inglês

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tradução

Quem faz a tradução dos textos? poderia verificar em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges as medalhas que estão com descrição em Inglês.

- `Curioso` - Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record
- `Inquisitivo` - Ask a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintain a positive question record
- `Socrático` - Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record

Comment: Apenas a medalha `Socrático` (no meu caso) apareceu com a descrição em Inglês. Na verdade não é no Selecionar... é nas medalhas o problema, veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges ... Editei a pergunta, se não concordar, por favor faça o rollback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quem traduz é o próprio pessoal daqui. O site usado para fazer as traduções é o [transifex](https://www.transifex.com).

Existe um [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27048/traducao-do-sopt) que trata apenas das traduções do site, como eu não colaboro com a tradução não sei se ele serve para apontar os locais que não estão traduzidos, mas vale a pena ir até lá e dar uma olhada.

[Como você já sabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4598/18246), é bom (e recomendado, eu acho) postar aqui no meta os locais que faltam traduzir.